# How to use JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to consume data from an API using REST call . 
I've succeeded to get data from the API : 
You can check demo on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/33/

Now , I am trying to perform the work to get different resources from this API 
I am reading these two articles : 
 - http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/
 - http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/

I would like to know why do we use `JSON.stringify()` if we can show data in HTML pages .
Why do we use so-called 'class'/'model' to parse data using json ?

Regards ,

Comment: Is the question "How to use `JSON.stringify()`?" or "Why do we use `JSON.stringify()`?" (The answers would be quite different.)

Comment: The both ! If I don't get how do I use it because I don't get the idea behind why do we use it ?

Comment: Read over this page: http://json.org/

Comment: So more generally you want to know why you'd want to use JSON at all? JSON is a data interchange format, i.e., you use it to transfer data between systems. It provides a string representation of data, and most systems can read or write strings.

Comment: But i didn't find utility of using it . In my demo , I got results in my HTML page , Why do I need to use JSon in this case

Comment: well, the answer is, you don't :P

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You need to use JSON in your demo because the API you use returns the data in JSON format. I can't find `JSON.stringify()` anywhere in the jsfiddle code.

Comment: In your demo, the service you called provided the data back to your page in JSON format. [This](http://raxaemrtest.elasticbeanstalk.com/ws/rest/v1/raxacore/drug?q=ELMECOB) is what the response looked like. Because you specified `dataType:'json'` jQuery automatically parsed the JSON for you and passed the resulting object to your `success` function. Your `success` function then used the properties of that object to put text in the html it added to the page. If you weren't using jQuery you could instead use `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON yourself.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a data structure, which means it serves to transport variables, arrays and stuff.

Sending variables in html code would be silly - that is why we use JSON.

`JSON.stringify()` is an utility function, which is most commonly used for debugging, when you want to print some variable to console, but there are some other uses, too.

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(myObject) );
```

What the function does, is that it takes an object, array or about anything else, and makes a readable string of it, while simply using something like this ↓↓ would give you only [Object].

```
console.log( myObject );
```

If all you really want is to send some HTML to be displayed, then you don't need to bother with JSON at all, and just use `jQuery.load()` or something similar.

Comment: You can actually transport data using HTML. But is is not meant for such a use case!

Comment: Thanks !  Why do we use so-called 'class'/'model' to parse data using json ?

Comment: What the hell is 'class'/'model'?

Comment: check this page : https://github.com/UNDEADgtr/JQueryRest/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/cars.js#L211-269 . a 'Car' in this case is a model

Comment: As far as I know, I don't use 'class'/'model' to parse data using json.  Part of the advantage of JSON inside Javascript is that it's already in a usable format.  I can simply navigate the object tree represented by a JSON string (once it's been parsed) with native JS techniques.

Comment: Scott : Can you check this my demo please : http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/33/ , Do I need to use Json here if I have already showing data in the page

Comment: It looks like it works, why would you want to complicate things by introducing unnecessary overhead?

Comment: Why do you insist on somehow adding JSON to something that already works, without even knowing why you should do it. It's not like there's some unearthly force that makes you use it everywhere.

Comment: The demo _already_ uses JSON, you just don't see it because jQuery handled it for you internally in its `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: ...Unless, of course, he wants to transfer some extra data together with the page. Then he could get the HTML as a string in a JSON..

Comment: @Epsilon_G: You are using JSON for your transport.  jQuery is handling the mechanics of doing the conversion for you client-side.  In your `success: function (data) { /* ... */ }`, `data` is the result of converting the JSON string to a Javascript object.  You're already there!

Comment: @MightyPork : Exactly , This is what I am going to do ! I am not going to get one thing but extra data by writing different functions using different rest calls . That's why I am asking about 'Model'/Json .

Comment: @Epsilon_G: I would suggest you write a few of them first before jumping to the abstraction, especially someone else's abstraction that may mean little for your project.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet : I did that , I've written two functions OBS_omrsRestCall(URL);
drug_omrsRestCall(URL); You can comment one of these to run the other one . I am sharing code with you  : http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/34/

Comment: @Epsilon_G: I don't see the "OBS" one.  But regardless, this is your call, not mine.  You need to try a few different examples, then see if there are similarities that can be abstracted.  I was simply suggesting that you don't start by assuming this other abstraction and trying to apply it to your own circumstance when you're not even clear what it's abstracting away.  Good luck!

Comment: @ScottSauyet : Thanks for your help  , The two functions that I was mentioning are in the main function .  
$(document).ready(function () {
    
OBS_omrsRestCall(REST_OBS);

//drug_omrsRestCall(REST_Drug);

});

Comment: @Epsilon_G: I don't know why I didn't see the OBS functions.  And Chrome's search was being funky too.  I definitely see a lot of commonality in how you fetch your data.  So you might want to define a common function for that.  But how you process the data seems distinct.  So perhaps you should define just a common bit for fetching JSON data that accepts (only?) the url.  Again, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will agreee that in javascript code JSON objects are nice and easy to use, for example

```
var jsonObj { "p1": "1", "p2": "2"};

if ( jsonObj.p1 == '1' ) { // do something }
```

But if we want to pass that object around to non javascript code, for example to a PHP script, we cannot do it. 
So the stringify comes into play, we stringify our JSON object i.e. convert the whole object to a string, now we can pass this around to anything that has the ability to convert it back to something useful. So PHP has the json_decode() function to convert a stringified json object/array to a PHP object/array so it becomes useful again.
Now when we want to pass data back from PHP to javascript we convert a PHP object/array to a json string using json_encode() and we can now pass an object/array back to a javascript as a string for it to use JSON.parse() on so it can convert it back to a usable object/array.

So in summary, stringify allows us to convert language specific formats for objects/arrays into a universally available format i.e. a string. Therefore any language that provides a method of converting this stringified format into its own language specific formats for objects/arrays can use this data and of course return it again via the stringified format.

Comment: Note that not all JavaScript objects can be represented as JSON (because objects can have properties that refer to functions, and can have circular references, etc.).